# Move menu bar to the bottom of the screen

Tags: raspbian

I have a new Raspberry Pi 2 with the latest version of Raspbian OS. I launched the Pi and noticed that the menu bar is on the top, which I do not like. Is there a way to move it to the bottom of the screen like a Windows OS or OSX?

Comment: For future reference, GNU/Linux systems are heterogeneous when it comes to the desktop, and the default used on Raspbian is [LXDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXDE).   You can use something else if you want, but more importantly, if you are using it and you are looking for information, remember to include "LXDE" when searching online.

Comment: ...Also I'm sure there's a way to move it where ever you want, but I don't know what it is for LXDE.   The more generic term for menu/task bars is "panel".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click the menu bar and choose a new position in the Geometry tab of panel settings.

This is also worth a read as to why its on the top.

http://www.raspberrypi.org/changes-to-the-raspbian-user-interface/

Comment: +1 But wow: I despise programmers/designers justifying themselves with excessive psychologism and pretending the subjective is objective.  "Right" vs. "wrong" in the position of a task bar is a new low.  I do not "instinctively" look in the top left corner and even if I did, it does not mean everything in life should be piled there and/or that as a user I should be reduced to pure instinct.   IMO just plain *NO TASK BAR* is the "right" way to style a GUI interface, and Simon Long should stick to math or whatever it is he's actually good at. $0.02